# SwiftUI – Navigation bar "isTranscluent" property crashes on iPad

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationlink

How to set the `isTranscluent` property for iPad navigation bar using SwiftUI. The below code works fine in iPhone but crashes in iPad with error: `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.4 / iPad Air3. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Asperi Did you checked with SwiftUI?

Comment: Definitely I did :)

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in Xcode 12.0 Beta (iPad Pro 2018 with iPadOS 13.5) using UIKit :

```
navigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Also works fine in Xcode 12.0 Beta (iPad Pro 2018 with iPadOS 13.5) using SwiftUI :

```
struct NavigationConfigurator: UIViewControllerRepresentable { ... }

NavigationView {

    ScrollView {
        Text("Scroll View")
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Navigation Bar", displayMode: .inline)
    .background(NavigationConfigurator { controller in
        controller.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        controller.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : .grey]
        controller.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    })
}
```